# How to find Lagrange multipliers corresponding to constraints?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a constrained optimisation problem that I solved using Mathematica's FindMinimum function. I would like to know how to get the dual variables corresponding to the constraints I have. Obviously they will be zero for interior solutions and non-zero else, but I would like to look at them all the same.

My problem looks like this:

> > $\text{Lin}=\text{FindMinimum}\left[\left\{0.3 e^{-\text{z2}} \left(0.09 e^{-(x+\text{z1})}+0.3 e^{-y}\right)+0.09 e^{-(x+\text{z1})}+0.3 e^{-x}+0.3 e^{-y}+0.3 e^{-z},x+y+z+\text{z1}+\text{z2}\leq 100,x\geq 0,y\geq 0,z\geq 0,\text{z1}\geq 0,\text{z2}\geq 0\right\},\{x,y,z,\text{z1},\text{z2}\}\right]$

Comment: From the `FindMinimum` result you can determine which are the binding constraints, and then write down the corresponding Lagrangian equation(s) and use `NSolve` or `FindRoot` to solve for the multipliers.

Answer (score 2):

A nice little function `KT` (based on `Reduce`) that provides both optimal variables and corresponding Lagrange multipliers for simple and small problems can be found [here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2014/03/using-reduce-to-compute-nash-equilibria/)

The following code takes about 15sec to evaluate on my pc:

```
f = (3/10)*Exp[-z2]*((9/100)*Exp[-(x + z1)] + (3/10)*Exp[-y]) + 
(9/100)*Exp[-(x + z1)] + (3/10)*Exp[-x] + (3/10)*Exp[-y] + (3/10)*Exp[-z];

cons={x + y + z + z1 + z2 <= 100, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0, z1 >= 0, z2 >= 0};

KT[-f, cons, {x, y, z, z1, z2}]
```

> ```
> x == 1/3 (100 - 3 Log[2] - 3 Log[5] - Log[13] + 2 Log[139]) && 
> y == 1/3 (100 + 2 Log[13] - Log[139]) && 
> z == 1/3 (100 + 3 Log[2] + 3 Log[5] - Log[13] - Log[139]) && 
> z1 == 0 && 
> z2 == 0 && 
> \[Lambda][1] == (3 1807^(1/3))/(100 E^(100/3)) && 
> \[Lambda][2] == 0 && 
> \[Lambda][3] == 0 && 
> \[Lambda][4] == 0 && 
> \[Lambda][5] == (3 13^(1/3))/(139^(2/3) E^(100/3)) && 
> \[Lambda][6] == 3819/(100 1807^(2/3) E^(100/3))
> ```

The multipliers correspond to the constraints as entered in `cons`, i.e., $\lambda_1$ corresponds to the sum constraint and the remaining multipliers to the non-negative constraints. Evaluating `f` for the above values gives `3.65942*10^-15`.

On the other hand, using `FindMinimum` may give a local minimizer depending on the initial values as the following test case shows:

```
FindMinimum[{f,And@cons}, {{x, 10}, {y, 10}, {z, 10}, {z1, 10}, {z2, 10}}]
```

> ```
> {9.68425*10^-7, {x -> 13.7422, y -> 13.7422, z -> 13.7423, 
>   z1 -> 13.1105, z2 -> 13.1105}}
> ```